# DocuSign JWT authentications through ApiClient calss (JAVA SDK), point to strange ip address

Tags: docusignapi

We are going into integration test of an application using DocuSign API with aid of their Java SDK. The application authenticates itself through the **ApiClient.requestJWTUserToken**, with the demo basepath **https://demo.docusign.net/restapi**, and in develop environment it works.
In integration environment there is a firewall with a whitelist for allowed addresses, and we allowed **https://demo.docusign.com** and **https://account-d.docusign.com**. During the authentication stage, the firewall drops a connection attempt to **64.207.216.101**, which is strange since the account-d.docusign.com resolves to **64.207.216.102**.

Anyone can suppose what's happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. The range is 64.207.216.1 through 64.207.219.254. You can find our IP ranges in this [guide](https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature)

Comment: I think the link is wrong.

Comment: My bad, should work now